# HapiJS scopes: Custom error message instead of "Insufficient scope"

Tags: node.js, hapi.js

I'm using HapiJS for my REST API. I'm also using scopes functionality to implement simple role-based access to resources. Example route configuration objects looks like this:

```
{
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/users/{userID}',
    config: {
        auth: {
            access: {
                scope: ['user-{params.userID}']
            }
        },
        handler: getUserHandler
    }
}
```

By default when currently authenticated user doesn't have `scope` required to access given endpoint (eg. `scope: 'user-1'` when trying to GET `/users/1`), there's an error response returned:

`{"statusCode":403,"error":"Forbidden","message":"Insufficient scope"}`

What I want is to **replace this `403` error with a custom status code** and error message – I want to return `404 Not Found` instead. And I want to do this **only for certain endpoints**. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it through `server.ext('onPostHandler', (request, reply) => {...`

You can get the `route` and `response` object inside request.

The `response` object contains `isBoom`, if it is true, you should get the `response.output.statusCode` which you may validate if it is `403`.

The `route` object contains the `path` which you may validate if it is the endpoint you want.

Something like this:

```js
server.ext('onPostHandler', (request, reply) => {

  const response = request.response;

  if (response.isBoom &&
     response.output.statusCode === 403 &&
     request.route.path === 'your_endpoint') {
    
    // your code here
  }

  return reply.continue();
});
```